# How to test or simulate draging a file from desktop to browser in selenium webdriver using Java

Tags: java, javascript, selenium-webdriver

How to test draging a file from desktop to browser in selenium webdriver using java? I know we can do in Helium, but we are not ready for commercial product.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please review the help section of the site [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Typically, questions suggesting "can you suggest a Code Library, Practice, etc" are flagged and closed on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Using PyWinAuto you can achieve this, but it will not be consistent as Pywinauto does not Support Web Based Applications.

```
Steps Can be- 
Step 1 - Minimize ur browser using Pywinauto Window.Minimize Method.
Step 2- Mouse Click and Hold on the Icon
Step 3 - Maximize ur Broser using Window.Maximize
Step 4- Click on any coordinate on the browser and release the mouse.
```

But It may  not be a full proof solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Autoit** for this scenario.

Dig this one:
http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/upload-a-file-using-selenium-webdriver-with-autoit

Answer (score 0):

```html
Attach()

Func Attach()

WinWait("Open")
While True
    $win = WinWait("Open", "")

 ControlFocus($win, "", "Open")
Send("{t 1}")
Send("{e 1}")
Send("{s 1}")
Send("{t 1}")
Send("{. 1}")
Send("{p 1}")
Send("{n 1}")
Send("{g 1}")
 Sleep(2000)
    ControlClick($win, "", "[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]")
    WinWaitClose($win)
 Wend


EndFunc
```